# XCode 4.2: Where do I find upgrade current target for ipad?

Tags: ios, xcode4

I upgraded my XCode to 4.2. But now I can't find upgrade current target for ipad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find solutions: Right-click the target and click Duplicate. Choose to Duplicate and Transition to iPad.

Answer (score 1):

Select your build target and the summary tab.  From here you can set your devices to 'Universal' changing the device will perform the same actions that 'update current target for iPad'.  It creates a MainWindow-iPad nib file sized for iPad and loads your root view controller into it.